# Class-only generic constraints in Swift

Tags: swift, class, generics, protocols, anyobject

I'm trying to mark a variable of a generic type as weak:

```
class X<T> {
  weak var t: T?
}
```

If I don't put in any constraints for `T` I get the error `weak cannot be applied to non-class type 'T'`.

If I would only use use this with NSObject derived classes this would work:

```
class X<T: NSObject> {
  weak var t: T?
}
```

But I also want to be able to use pure Swift classes.

For protocols it is possible to require that the implementor is of class type by using the `class` keyword:

```
protocol ClassType: class {
}
```

With the `ClassType` protocol I can now mark the variable as weak:

```
class X<T: ClassType> {
  weak var t: T?
}
```

But I cannot add the `class` keyword directly to the generic parameter:

```
class X<T: class> { // Compile error
  weak var t: T?
}
```

I can make the protocol solution work for all NSObject derived classes with an extension:

```
extension NSObject: ClassType {
}
```

But for pure Swift classes there is no common superclass that I could add this extension to. Is there a way to make this work without adding the `ClassType` protocol to each class I want to use the `X` class with? E.g. some special qualifier for the generic parameter like `class X<T:ThisIsAClass>`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You want `AnyObject`, which the Swift docs describe as:

> The protocol to which all classes implicitly conform.

```
class X<T: AnyObject> {
    weak var t: T?
}

class C { }
let x = X<C>()  // works fine
x.t = C()  

// error: type 'Int' does not conform to protocol ‘AnyObject’
// (because Int is a struct)
let y = X<Int>()
```

Comment: Is there any way to make it work with the protocol that has a class bound?
(e.g. to be able to create `protocol Interface: class { }` and then create subclass `class Y: X<Interface> { }`)

Comment: **Found an answer:** You need to add the `@objc` attribute to the protocol declaration and it works as well `@objc protocol Interface: class { }`