# Protocol of reference type to generic constraint of type AnyObject

Tags: swift, class, generics, protocols, anyobject

I have a generic struct declared as follows:

```
struct WeakReference<T: AnyObject> {
    weak var value: T?

    init(value: T?) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

And a protocol:

```
protocol SomeProtocol: class {

}
```

But I'm not able to declare a variable of type of `WeakReference<SomeProtocol>`, the compiler complains that

> 'WeakReference' requires that `SomeProtocol` be a class type

Interestingly, in Swift, the `class` is a typealias of AnyObject.

I actually want to hold an array of `WeakReference<SomeProtocol>` because the array holds strong references.

[Class-only generic constraints in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28884867/class-only-generic-constraints-in-swift) is a similar question but doesn't really solve this problem.

How can we pass the `SomeProtocol` to `WeakReference`?

**EDIT:**
The following scenario compiles fine, but we lose the ability to hold weak reference:

```
struct Reference<T> {
    var value: T?

    init(value: T?) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

var array: [Reference<SomeProtocol>] = []
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats simple. You are passing `SomeProtocol` which is a `protocol`. You need to pass there specific class type.

Eample:

```
class SomeImplementation: SomeProtocol {
}

var weakSome: WeakReference<SomeImplementation> = ...
```

Or you can bypass it by marking the protocol with `@objc` annotation, but I am not a fan of this approach.

```
@objc protocol SomeProtocol: class {

}

var weakSome: WeakReference<SomeProtocol> = ...
```

Try checking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself/43408193#43408193), it might provide you more context on the issue.

Comment: The problem is I want to hold an array of weak references of the classes that conform to protocol `SomeProtocol`. It works if we don't have the constraint `<T: AnyObject>`. But then we can't have weak references.

Comment: I have edited the the question to show this same case.

Comment: I would suggest creating a specific `SomeWeakBox` where the `value` property will be `SomeProtocol` and definition of some protocol will be constrained to class types `protocol SomeProtocol: class`. Then you can simply have array `let array: [SomeWeakBox] = []`

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about this approach?

```
class WeakReference<T> {
    weak var value: AnyObject?

    init(value: T?) {
        self.value = value as? AnyObject
    }
}

protocol SomeProtocol: class {

}

class A: SomeProtocol { }

let araayOfSomeProtocolObjects: [SomeProtocol] = (0...5).map {_ in A() }
let arrayOfWeakReferences: [WeakReference<SomeProtocol>] = araayOfSomeProtocolObjects.map { WeakReference(value: $0) }

for item in arrayOfWeakReferences {
    print(item.value is A) // true
}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I hold an array of weak references of objects which conform to `SomeProtocol` with this approach?

Comment: This doesn't compile. Can't use `WeakReference<SomeProtocol>`. That's the whole problem.

Comment: @Shubham strange, i have compiled without problem on latest Xcode. Can you provide error image or something?

Comment: @Shubham I also attached playground screenshot

Comment: I'm sorry I overlooked that you removed the generic constraint in `WeakReference`. This compiles and works fine. The only downside is that we have to typecast the `value` to `SomeProtocol` every time we use it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should solve your problem.

```
struct WeakReference<T> {
    private weak var privateRef: AnyObject?
    var ref: T? {
        get { return privateRef as? T }
        set { privateRef = newValue as AnyObject }
    }

    init(_ ref: T? = nil) {
        self.ref = ref
    }
}

// usage
protocol MyProto: class { }
extension UIViewController: MyProto { }

let vc = UIViewController()
var weakRef = WeakReference<MyProto>(vc)
print(weakRef.ref)
```

You obviously can use `WeakReference` with non class protocol or non bridged value types.
If you try that, you'll get always `nil`.

P.S. : Try this code on a real Xcode project because in the Playground doesn't work as expected.