# Why doesn't an AnyObject constraint on a generic parameter allow that generic parameter to be used as a constraint?

Tags: swift, generics, generic-constraints

While playing around with the code in another SO post, I found this interesting behaviour.

As we know, the type of a `weak var` needs to be a class type and the type used in a generic constraint needs to be a class type, or a protocol type.

Therefore, this does not compile:

```
class Foo<T> {
    weak var bar: T? // error
    func foo<U: T>(u: U) {} // error
}
```

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28884867/class-only-generic-constraints-in-swift), I can put an `AnyObject` constraint (or any protocol that has a `: class` constraint) on `T` to remove the first error:

```
class Foo<T: AnyObject> {
    weak var bar: T?
    func foo<U: T>(u: U) {} // error
}
```

But the second error still remains:

> Type 'U' constrained to non-protocol, non-class type 'T'

The compiler seems to be lying through its teeth right here. By removing the first error the compiler has just admitted that `T` indeed is a class type, and now it's saying it isn't.

Why is this happening? Did they just not design this feature?

Comment: Is there any situation where you can chain generic parameters like that, `<U: T>`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It came from a failed attempt of me trying to simulate some generic variance in Swift, which I know is only supported for arrays.

Comment: I added `U: AnyObject` to the class header and still got the same error. To me it looks like the limitation is that you can’t constrain a generic parameter with another generic parameter (in any situation).

Comment: So it's another case of confusing error messages, then? It should have said something like "generic parameters are not allowed to be used as generic constraints". @JoakimDanielson